# How come when I try to render something in the application, it doesn't show up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my layouts folder, filename `application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>One Month Rails</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% render 'layouts/header' %>

        <%= yield %>

        <% render 'layouts/footer' %>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have this in my layouts folder, filename `_header.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
<%= link_to "About", about_path %>
```

After I save the code and refresh the page, the changes doesn't take place

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a partial, thus you must rename to `_header.html.erb` and change the .erb to `<%= render 'layouts/header' %>`

Please read the documentation about [Using Partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) in rails docs.

Comment: Also, it should be `<%= render 'layouts/header' %>`.

Comment: I forgot the "=" after the "%". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need at least the following files:

```
/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb
/app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb
```

I assume you have the proper routes for `root_path` and `about_path`.